# AngularJS Apply filters in multiple fields

Tags: html, angularjs

My target is to search my notes by **Title** and truncate **Body** by a letters or words limit. I don't know if its possible to do that and how. I don't want to mess up with any custom filters , directives etc.

This is a idea of the html:

```
<section class="notespage" ng-controller="NotesController">
 <h2>Notes list</h2>

 <div>
  Search:
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
 </div>

 <div class="notesleft">
  <div class="notelist">  
   <div ng-repeat="note in notes | filter:searchText | truncate:{body:letterLimit}">
    <div><h3>{{note.title}}</h3></div>
    <div>{{note.body}}</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Where this should be ?  In NotesController ?

```
$scope.letterLimit = 20 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to "mess up" with custom filters etc, you can use the built-in **[limitTo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/U589g/)** filter to limit the number of characters displayed as `note.body`:

```
$scope.letterLimit = 20;

<div>Search:<input type="search" ng-model="searchText" /></div>
<div ng-repeat="note in notes | filter:searchText">
    <div><h3>{{note.title}}</h3></div>
    <div>{{note.body | limitTo:letterLimit}}</div>
<div>
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/U589g/)**.